# Why does valgrind point to a memory leak at libc-start.c?

Tags: memory-leaks, valgrind

After building an app, it keeps crashing due to some memory leak. The beginning of the valgrind report reads:

```
==70588==
==70588== HEAP SUMMARY:
==70588==     in use at exit: 215,842 bytes in 2,327 blocks
==70588==   total heap usage: 77,289 allocs, 74,962 frees, 7,513,045 bytes allocated
==70588==
==70588== 20 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 182 of 510
==70588==    at 0x4849D8C: malloc (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/valgrid/vgpreload_memcheck-arm64-linux.so
==70588==    by 0x15481F: ??? (in /usr/bin/tcsh)
==70588==    by 0x15C313: ??? (in /usr/bin/tcsh)
==70588==    by 0x117EAB: ??? (in /usr/bin/tcsh)
==70588==    by 0x492C08F: (below main) (libc-start.c:308)
```

A similar message is repeated for several records but the strange thing is that it always points to libc-start.c, which doesn't provide much insight into which piece of the app is causing the memory leak (the app itself has tens of thousands of lines with a mix of C/Fortran and many internal dependencies). Any suggestions on what might be the root of the problem or what to look at would be welcomed.

Comment: If, as the "HEAP SUMMARY" states, a total of 7,513,045 bytes were allocated, what causes you to believe that the program died due to a memory leak?  That number is just not all that large.

Comment: When the app crashed, the error message indicated a memory leak. What else could be causing the loss of all those bytes signaled by valgrind?

Comment: The libc-start.c is just an entry point of your program (which initializes stack, memory allocator, etc. and jumps to `main`). The real allocation happens in `tcsh`. You need to build it with debuginfo or [install debug symbols](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages) to understand what's going on.